# For getting bounce back mails in Linux

Tags: java, linux, shell, linux-kernel

If I am sending a mail from Linux it is working. If I am giving an invalid mail, in Linux I can fetch bounce back mails. Like this for creating a mail:

```
echo "HIII" | mail -s subject diljish.chandran@gmail.com
```

If I am giving like:

```
echo "HIII" | mail -s subject diljish.chandrangmailcom
```

it will fail and from Linux I can fetch bounce back mail for invalid mail

But, if `diljish@gmail.com` is not existing inside gmail.com, through linux I am not getting any bounce back mails. But, if I am trying through Microsoft outlook, I am getting a bounce back mails. Why?

Comment: What is your mail client?

Comment: Not a programming question, try serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

You might find them in

```
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.info
```

mail.err is the one you are looking for. But it would be better if you mention your distro and mail client, to get better answer.